# Doctrine 2. Cannot redeclare class Setup

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Sometimes I see an error that occurs when the page loads, which points to the base class initialize Doctrine 2 Setup.

The problem is that the error occurs through time and quite often, so catch the cause-effect relationship is extremely difficult. However, I am sure that this problem has already met someone. And it may be able to prompt a response.

Thanks in advance.

Error string: **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class doctrine\orm\tools\setup in /....hidden path..../lib/DoctrineORM/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php on line 34**

```php
<?php
namespace Doctrine\ORM\Tools;

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver;

/**
 * Convenience class for setting up Doctrine from different installations and configurations.
 *
 * @author Benjamin Eberlei <kontakt@beberlei.de>
 */
class Setup
{
    /**
     * Use this method to register all autoloaders for a setup where Doctrine is checked out from
     * its github repository at {@link http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2}
     *
     * @param string $gitCheckoutRootPath
     * @return void
     */
    static public function registerAutoloadGit($gitCheckoutRootPath)
    {
        if (!class_exists('Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader', false)) {
            require_once $gitCheckoutRootPath . "/lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php";
        }

        $loader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', $gitCheckoutRootPath . "/lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib");
        $loader->register();

        $loader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine\DBAL', $gitCheckoutRootPath . "/lib/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib");
        $loader->register();

        $loader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine\ORM', $gitCheckoutRootPath . "/lib");
        $loader->register();

        $loader = new ClassLoader('Symfony\Component', $gitCheckoutRootPath . "/lib/vendor");
        $loader->register();
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to register all autoloaders for a setup where Doctrine is installed
     * though {@link http://pear.doctrine-project.org}.
     *
     * This method registers autoloaders for both Doctrine and Symfony top
     * level namespaces.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    static public function registerAutoloadPEAR()
    {
        if (!class_exists('Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader', false)) {
            require_once "Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php";
        }

        $loader = new ClassLoader("Doctrine");
        $loader->register();

        $loader = new ClassLoader("Symfony");
        $loader->register();

        $classLoader = new ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', $lib . 'DoctrineExtensions');
        $classLoader->register();
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to register all autoloads for a downloaded Doctrine library.
     * Pick the directory the library was uncompressed into.
     *
     * @param string $directory
     */
    static public function registerAutoloadDirectory($directory)
    {
        if (!class_exists('Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader', false)) {
            require_once $directory . "/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php";
        }

        $loader = new ClassLoader("Doctrine", $directory);
        $loader->register();

        $loader = new ClassLoader('Symfony\Component', $directory . "/Doctrine");
        $loader->register();

        $classLoader = new ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', $directory);
        $classLoader->register();
    }

    /**
     * Create a configuration with an annotation metadata driver.
     *
     * @param array $paths
     * @param boolean $isDevMode
     * @param string $proxyDir
     * @param Cache $cache
     * @param bool $useSimpleAnnotationReader
     * @return Configuration
     */
    static public function createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array $paths, $isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null, $useSimpleAnnotationReader = true)
    {
        $config = self::createConfiguration($isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache);
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($paths, $useSimpleAnnotationReader));
        return $config;
    }

    /**
     * Create a configuration with a xml metadata driver.
     *
     * @param array $paths
     * @param boolean $isDevMode
     * @param string $proxyDir
     * @param Cache $cache
     * @return Configuration
     */
    static public function createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array $paths, $isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null)
    {
        $config = self::createConfiguration($isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache);
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl(new XmlDriver($paths));
        return $config;
    }

    /**
     * Create a configuration with a yaml metadata driver.
     *
     * @param array $paths
     * @param boolean $isDevMode
     * @param string $proxyDir
     * @param Cache $cache
     * @return Configuration
     */
    static public function createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array $paths, $isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null)
    {
        $config = self::createConfiguration($isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache);
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl(new YamlDriver($paths));
        return $config;
    }

    /**
     * Create a configuration without a metadata driver.
     *
     * @param bool $isDevMode
     * @param string $proxyDir
     * @param Cache $cache
     * @return Configuration
     */
    static public function createConfiguration($isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null)
    {
        $proxyDir = $proxyDir ?: sys_get_temp_dir();
        if ($isDevMode === false && $cache === null) {
            if (extension_loaded('apc')) {
                $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
            } else if (extension_loaded('xcache')) {
                $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\XcacheCache();
            } else if (extension_loaded('memcache')) {
                $memcache = new \Memcache();
                $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1');
                $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
                $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
            } else if (extension_loaded('redis')) {
                $redis = new \Redis();
                $redis->connect('127.0.0.1');
                $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache();
                $cache->setRedis($redis);
            } else {
                $cache = new ArrayCache();
            }
        } else if ($cache === null) {
            $cache = new ArrayCache();
        }
        $cache->setNamespace("dc2_" . md5($proxyDir) . "_"); // to avoid collisions

        $config = new Configuration();
        $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
        $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
        $config->setResultCacheImpl($cache);
        $config->setProxyDir($proxyDir);
        $config->setProxyNamespace('DoctrineProxies');
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($isDevMode);

        return $config;
    }
}
```

Comment: The "cannot redeclare class" often means there is another class called Setup somewhere.

Comment: Sometimes I face such error when there is more than one cache storage enabled and used...

Comment: Yes, maybe it's a problem, because I use Doctrine 2 with modx revo. And both use cache permanently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was duplicated load entities.